# Spring boot and jwt Encoded password does not look like BCrypt

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

I know there are several questions about this, but none of them helped, everything seemed ok to me... I hope I'm wrong about this.
I've followed [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot-api) to create authentication with JWT for my Spring Boot application, but I'm stuck with this warning

```
 o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
```

This is the class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {



    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;



    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;



    public WebSecurity(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()       
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()));
    }



    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
}
```

And this is the class that implements UserDetailsService:

```
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {



    private ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository;



    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository) {
        this.applicationUserRepository = applicationUserRepository;
    }



    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("loadUserByUsername");
        ApplicationUser applicationUser = applicationUserRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (applicationUser == null) {
            System.out.println("User non trovato");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        System.out.println("Username: " + applicationUser.getUsername());
        return new User(applicationUser.getUsername(), applicationUser.getPassword(), emptyList());
    }

}
```

Also, I'm wondering where the class WebSecurity is istantiated with the correct parameters passed. Is this managed automatically by Spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, it was that my class UserDetailsServiceImpl did not have the "@Service" annotation. Now it's working fine.